# AWS QnA Bot Solution change the Alexa welcome message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have an [AWS QnA Bot](https://github.com/aws-solutions/aws-qnabot) that I am using with Alexa. The default welcome message for Alexa with this solution is:
"Hello, Please ask a question".

I'd like to change this to make it more personalized for my bot but I'm not sure where to make this change in the Lambda code.

I went into the Lambda function that the [built-in tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HcPK.png) told me to use for the Alexa Skill endpoint. Here, I found a section called `get_welcome_message` that looks like this:

```html
async function get_welcome_message(req, locale){
    console.log("=================" + JSON.stringify(req));
    const welcome_message = _.get(req,'_settings.DEFAULT_ALEXA_LAUNCH_MESSAGE', 'Hello, Please ask a question');
    if (_.get(req._settings, 'ENABLE_MULTI_LANGUAGE_SUPPORT')){
        return await translate.get_translation(welcome_message,'en',locale,req)
    } else {
        return welcome_message;
    }
}
```

I thought that changing the `welcome_message` would change it in the Alexa skill. However, no matter what I change it to, it will still say: ["Hello, Please ask a question"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi6Mr.png).

I've tried clearing my history/cache in case that was an issue. I've deployed the altered Lambda, rebuilt the AWS QnA Bot, and rebuilt the Alexa Skill. I've also looked through the Lambda and this function seems to be the only place where a welcome message is set. It looks like everything that requires the welcome message calls this middleware.

This seems like it should be a simple task to change but I just can't seem to get it to show a different welcome message.

Please let me know how I can change this default welcome message. I feel like it's something simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach would be to change the value of `DEFAULT_ALEXA_LAUNCH_MESSAGE` from Content Designer UI. This doesn't require any code changes.

You can find the instructions to access content designer [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-question-and-answer-bot-with-amazon-lex-and-amazon-alexa/#creating-content). [Here](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/20c56f9e-9c0a-4174-a661-9f40d9f063ac/en-US/deployment/configuration) is how you can change the settings.